# Treat inherited Activities as the same for Reorder to Front

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I have a project with 3 Activites A, B and C. Activity B extends A.

A and B should be single instance, so I add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to my intents when switching activities.
 This works correctly in that navigating A > B > A > C > B gives me the back stack A > C > B only.

But ideally I want A and B to be treated the same in the context of the backstack as they appear the same to the user, they just have differences under the cover.

This isn't my own project so I don't have the flexibility to change the Activity structure. Is there a way to make A and B be treated as the same? I tried taskAffinity but I don't want the separate entry on recents nor the visible switch/animation to a new task. I also considered CLEAR_TOP, but it is important not to remove other activies from the stack (ie C)

What I expect is that navigating A > B > A > C > B should give me the back stack C > B only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to have Android treat these 2 Activities the same in terms of the back stack.

You should move the code from ActivityB to ActivityA and use an "extra" in the `Intent` to indicate whether the Activity should behave like `A` or like `B`. This is the only way to be able to ensure that either `A` or `B` will be in the stack, but not both.